# I cant run my app in Marshmallow. How can i solve this?

Tags: android, sqlite

I can run my app up to *Android 5.1.1*. But cant enter to home page up to Android 6(DB is created and data can insert here), app stop working forcefully here.

*Above Android 6* DB is not creating. can any one provide a solution...

**DBHelper class**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String DatabaseName="/mnt/sdcard/Hmeauto1_DB.db";
    private static final int DatabaseVersion=1;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public String c=null;





        public static final String Query = "CREATE TABLE " + UserConstruct.newUserinfo.TableName + " ( " + UserConstruct.newUserinfo.Id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + UserConstruct.newUserinfo.UserName + " TEXT, " + UserConstruct.newUserinfo.Password + " TEXT," + UserConstruct.newUserinfo.FName + " TEXT, " + UserConstruct.newUserinfo.LName + " TEXT," + UserConstruct.newUserinfo.ACode + " TEXT," + UserConstruct.newUserinfo.AEmail + " TEXT, " + UserConstruct.newUserinfo.User_Type + " TEXT);";

        public static final String Query1 = "CREATE TABLE  " + UserConstruct.add_home.TableName + " ( " + UserConstruct.add_home.Home_Id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + UserConstruct.add_home.Home_Name + " TEXT, " + UserConstruct.add_home.Home_Number + " INTEGER, " + UserConstruct.add_home.UserName + " TEXT);";

        public static final String Query2 = "CREATE TABLE  " + UserConstruct.add_Floors.TableName + " ( " + UserConstruct.add_Floors.Flr_Id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + UserConstruct.add_Floors.Home_Id + " INTEGER, " + UserConstruct.add_Floors.Flr_Name + " TEXT, " + UserConstruct.add_Floors.Flr_Number + " INTEGER, " + UserConstruct.add_Floors.UserName + " TEXT ;";

        public static final String Query3 = "CREATE TABLE  " + UserConstruct.add_Rooms.TableName + " ( " + UserConstruct.add_Rooms.Room_Id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + UserConstruct.add_Rooms.Flr_Id + " INTEGER, " + UserConstruct.add_Rooms.Home_Id + " INTEGER, " + UserConstruct.add_Rooms.Room_Name + " TEXT, " + UserConstruct.add_Rooms.Room_Number + " INTEGER, " + UserConstruct.add_Rooms.UserName + " TEXT ;";

        // public static final String Floor="CREATE TABLE "+UserConstruct.Floors.TableName+" ( "+UserConstruct.Floors.Flr_Id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+UserConstruct.Floors.Flr_Name+" TEXT);";
        public static final String Query4 = "CREATE TABLE  " + UserConstruct.image_list.TableName + " ( " + UserConstruct.image_list.Id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + UserConstruct.image_list.Image_Name_fxd + " TEXT, " + UserConstruct.image_list.Image_Name + " TEXT, " + UserConstruct.image_list.Device_ID + " TEXT, " + UserConstruct.image_list.Home_Id + " INTEGER, " + UserConstruct.image_list.Flr_Id + " INTEGER, " + UserConstruct.image_list.Room_Id + " INTEGER, " + UserConstruct.image_list.UserName + " TEXT);";


        public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DatabaseName, null, DatabaseVersion);
            Log.e("Database operation", "created or opened";
            //  Log.d("path:", String.valueOf(context.getDatabasePath(DatabaseName)));

        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            try {
                db.execSQL(Query);
                Log.e("Created", "User Table Created";
                db.execSQL(Query1);
                Log.e("Created", "Add Home Table Created";
                db.execSQL(Query2);
                Log.e("Created", "Add Floor Table Created";
                db.execSQL(Query3);
                Log.e("Created", "Add Room Table Created";
                db.execSQL(Query4);
                Log.e("Created", "Add Room Table Created";
            }catch (RuntimeException e){e.printStackTrace();}


        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            try {
                String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + UserConstruct.newUserinfo.TableName;
                db.execSQL(query);
                String query1 = "DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + UserConstruct.add_Rooms.TableName;
                db.execSQL(query1);
                String query2 = "DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + UserConstruct.add_Floors.TableName;
                db.execSQL(query2);
                String query3 = "DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + UserConstruct.add_home.TableName;
                db.execSQL(query3);
                String query4 = "DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + UserConstruct.image_list.TableName;
                db.execSQL(query4);
            }catch(RuntimeException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            //  this.db=db;

        }

    public void insert(String Fname, String Lname, String Aemail, String Acode, String userName, String Password, String userType, SQLiteDatabase db) {
        ContentValues contentvalue = new ContentValues();
        contentvalue.put(UserConstruct.newUserinfo.FName, Fname);
        contentvalue.put(UserConstruct.newUserinfo.LName, Lname);
        contentvalue.put(UserConstruct.newUserinfo.AEmail, Aemail);
        contentvalue.put(UserConstruct.newUserinfo.ACode, Acode);
        contentvalue.put(UserConstruct.newUserinfo.UserName, userName);
        contentvalue.put(UserConstruct.newUserinfo.Password, Password);
        contentvalue.put(UserConstruct.newUserinfo.User_Type, userType);

        db.insert(UserConstruct.newUserinfo.TableName, null, contentvalue);
        Log.e("Insertion", "One row inserted";
        db.close();


    }
```

**Registering data**

```
View.OnClickListener adduserOnClickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
        fname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextFname);
        sname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextsname);
        email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        code=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextcode);
        Uname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextuser);
        pwrd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextpass);
        //utype=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerutype);

        String fname1 = fname.getText().toString();
        String lname1 = sname.getText().toString();
        String email1 = email.getText().toString();
        String code1 = code.getText().toString();
        String uname1 = Uname.getText().toString();
        String pswd1 = pwrd.getText().toString();
        String utype1 = "admin";


        if (fname1.equals("") {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter First Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (lname1.equals("") {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter Second Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (email1.equals("") {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter Email Id ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (code1.equals("") {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter Authentication Code ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (uname1.equals("") {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter User Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (pswd1.equals("") {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter Password ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
            try {
                sqlitedatabase = openOrCreateDatabase(DatabaseName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                Cursor allrows19 = sqlitedatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + UserConstruct.newUserinfo.TableName + " WHERE " + UserConstruct.newUserinfo.UserName + "=='" + uname1 + "'", null);
                if (allrows19.getCount() <= 0) {
                   // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    exist = false;

                } else if (allrows19.getCount() < 1) {
                    exist = false;
                   // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                allrows19.close();
                dbhelper.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }


            if (exist) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "This User Name not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else
            {
                dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                sqlitedatabase = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
                dbhelper.insert(fname1, lname1, email1, code1, uname1, pswd1, utype1, sqlitedatabase);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dbhelper.close();
                Registration.this.finish();
                Intent intent=new Intent(Registration.this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        }

   // }



        }catch (NullPointerException e){e.printStackTrace();}


    }
};
```

Comment: put your stack trash

Comment: am new in android.. Stack trash means?

Comment: I guess its because of  permission.you have to request permission for write database into sdcard at runtime for marshmallow

Comment: I had given run time permission for writing. And its now running when i run directly on phone. But not working when i generate an apk and install on same device.

Answer (score 0):

Change the db path to your app private path otherwise you need runtime `change sd card files` permissions to write data on sdcard

```
PackageManager m = getPackageManager(); 
String s = getPackageName(); 
try { 
       PackageInfo p = m.getPackageInfo(s, 0); 
       s = p.applicationInfo.dataDir; 
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
       Log.w("yourtag", "Error Package name not found ", e); 
}
```

So the s variable is your private app path

And provide some logcat logs if the above solution doesn't work

Comment: by private Koorosh is not meaning access modifier my friend, he is saying dont provide storage path, provide path which is related to you application, you can try my solution.

Comment: See the edited answer and use the s variable plus your db file name to create your database otherwise ask user for external storage permissions

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking if the user has granted permission of external storage by using:

```
if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
    return true;
}
```

If not, you need to ask the user to grant your app a permission:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Of course these are for marshmallow devices only so you need to check if your app is running on Marshmallow:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
      //do your check here
 }
```

Be also sure that your activity implements `OnRequestPermissionResult`

The entire permission looks like this:

```
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Permission result callback:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission: "+permissions[0]+ "was "+grantResults[0]);
        //resume tasks needing this permission
    }
}
```

Comment: can i run my app in Marshmellow if i set target sdk version 22?

Comment: Uninstall the application first, and then build again, even if it doesnt work goto Settings-->apps-->youApp-->permission. And check if storage permission is enabled or not

Comment: it is working when i directly run on my phone (Marshmallow). But when i generate apk and install on same phone is not working. I am confused.

Comment: I updated my answer, kindly check, you add run time permission for storage by this way in your launcher activity, then whenever user will open this app and storage permission is not enable he will get pop up for enabling storage permission.